# Set deny rule for images, now my function can't access it

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, wordpress, http-status-code-403

I've set a rule for my images in media folder. Here it is:

`<FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|php)$">
Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>`

This will prevent the visitors to directly gain access to the images. Now, whenever i call a php function like `getimagesize()` to get some data from an image, it returns an error, as you can guess:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in : C:.....

Now my question is, how can other functions and CMS's core files access my medias and generate thumbnails and stuff, but a function such as `getimagesize()` can't?

I'm calling this function right in the middle of a CMS load process, so it does have the same privileges as the CMS itself. How can i go around this? I only want outside visitors not to be able to access these files, not my installation of CMS itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a URL as the argument to `getimagesize()`, the request goes to web server, which will do what you have told it to do, that is, deny access to it.

You need to either use a filesystem path as the argument, or allow the IP address of your web server to access those files. You can see that IP address in your Apache `access.log`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as i mentioned in the error log, it is pointing to the folder name using absolute path (`C:\apache\htdocs\...`)

Comment: Then the most likely reason is the usage of Windows / MS-DOS style paths, and `getimagesize()` thinks this is a URL because of the colon. If possible, try to use relative paths.

Comment: This question is related to both php and Apache though. Can i update my question about getting image's dimension using related path or i have to ask another on stackoverflow?

Comment: Relative path is like `..\path\to\file`. Or in this case, you could use a relative path to the drive: `\path\to\file`.

Comment: Just one last thought. I was wondering to give a single php file full access to my images using `htaccess. Is it possible?

Comment: You allow just the IP address of the server, that is the easiest way.

Comment: But the ip is shared, i would do it if i had a dedicated ip address for my server. Thanks anyway, i will update the question and see what can i get.